# what happend if we create procedure without replace keyword

Tags: oracle

I create 1 procedure in oracle 10g , syntax of my stored procedure is:

```sql
create procedure procname is begin --query end;
```

I did not use `or replace` keyword when I execute this procedure. It gave me this message: procedure created with error.

What it exactly means my procedure is created or not and if it created will it replace my previous procedure because I have same procedure name before executing current procedure.

Answer (score 3):

The error message: `procedure created with error.` Means that your procedure was created but you will not be able to run it as it has errors.

You can use:

```sql
SHOW ERRORS;
```

immediately after the `CREATE PROCEDURE` DDL statement to show those errors or you can query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   user_errors
WHERE  name = 'YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME';
```

---

If you want to recreate the procedure then either use:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE your_procedure_name;
```

and then use `CREATE PROCEDURE ...`

or use:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Procedure was created (as message says), but it has errors.

There was no other procedure (or object) with that name, because you'd get "ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object" error message:

This is the first procedure, it was successfully created:

```
SQL> create procedure procname is
  2  begin
  3    null;
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.
```

Running another `create procedure`, using the same procedure name:

```
SQL> create procedure procname is
  2  begin
  3    null;
  4    --
  5    null;
  6  end;
  7  /
create procedure procname is
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object


SQL>
```

What if the "new" procedure had errors (missing `INTO` clause and *where* to put that value)? Nothing, the same message again:

```
SQL> create procedure procname is
  2  begin
  3    select * from dual;
  4  end;
  5  /
create procedure procname is
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object


SQL>
```

---

If you created a procedure that is invalid, then:

```
SQL> create procedure procname_2 is
  2  begin
  3    select * from dual;
  4  end;
  5  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE PROCNAME_2:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/3      PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
SQL>
```